# Compare values or string in PHP

Tags: php

I need to compare whether (1) contains (2).From the example below (2) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,18 are existed in (1).How can I check with the same in PHP

```
(1)1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25            
(2)1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,18
```

Comment: `array_intersect`

Comment: does the order matter ?

Comment: Are these meant to be 2 arrays? If so, are you wanting to see if any of the values exist in the other one or if all exist?

Comment: Just use explode both string by ,and use array_diff for not which are not exiting from one to another...

Comment: Can anyone give me an example.I will change it to any array if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = explode(',', $var1);
$array2 = explode(',', $var2);

$diff = array_diff($array2, $array1);
// return !count($diff);
```

Explode the strings in to arrays then use array_diff.

$diff will contain an array of items from $array2 not present in $array1.  If this array is empty, this means all the items exist in $array1.

You could also use array_intersect to see if the returned array is equal to array2:

```
$intersect = array_intersect($array2, $array1);
// return $array2 == $insersect;
```